# When splitting a regular expression in multiple lines - it stops working

Tags: python, regex, split

I have very long regular expression with numerous or|or|or:

```
re.findall(u'\W\s[A-Z]$|(com.|d\.)|\(?adj.\)?|(all\.$)|^(Pays|région|lieu-dit|chef-
lieu|canal|collégiale|ruisseau|bâtiment|hôpital|roi de|(bailliage|canton)(s?))|site|afflu(a|e)nt|forêt|village|église|état(s?)',
su)
```

I tried to split with \:

```
re.findall(u'\W\s[A-Z]$\
      |(com.|d\.) \
      |\(?adj.\)? \
      |(all\.$) \
      |^(Pays|région|lieu-dit \
      |chef-lieu 
       etc
```

When I split it like this - it stops workings, but Spyder does not yeld any errors - it just stops give the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You introduced whitespace at the start of the lines, as well as at the end of some:

```
>>> u'\W\s[A-Z]$\
...       |(com.|d\.) \
...       |\(?adj.\)? \
...       |(all\.$) \
...       |^(Pays|région|lieu-dit \
...       |chef-lieu '
u'\\W\\s[A-Z]$      |(com.|d\\.)       |\\(?adj.\\)?       |(all\\.$)       |^(Pays|r\xe9gion|lieu-dit       |chef-lieu '
```

If you want to split the string across multiple source lines, use either consecutive strings:

```
re.findall(u'\W\s[A-Z]$'
         u'|(com.|d\.)'
         u'|\(?adj.\)?'
         u'|(all\.$)'
         u'|^(Pays|région|lieu-dit'
            u'|chef-lieu|canal|collégiale|ruisseau|bâtiment|hôpital'
            u'|roi de|(bailliage|canton)(s?))'
         u'|site|afflu(a|e)nt'
         u'|forêt|village|église|état(s?)',
    sn
)
```

which Python will automatically join for you at compile time:

```
>>> (u'\W\s[A-Z]$'
...          u'|(com.|d\.)'
...          u'|\(?adj.\)?'
...          u'|(all\.$)'
...          u'|^(Pays|région|lieu-dit'
...             u'|chef-lieu|canal|collégiale|ruisseau|bâtiment|hôpital'
...             u'|roi de|(bailliage|canton)(s?))'
...          u'|site|afflu(a|e)nt'
...          u'|forêt|village|église|état(s?)')
u'\\W\\s[A-Z]$|(com.|d\\.)|\\(?adj.\\)?|(all\\.$)|^(Pays|r\xe9gion|lieu-dit|chef-lieu|canal|coll\xe9giale|ruisseau|b\xe2timent|h\xf4pital|roi de|(bailliage|canton)(s?))|site|afflu(a|e)nt|for\xeat|village|\xe9glise|\xe9tat(s?)'
```

Or use the verbose regular expression syntax:

```
re.findall(u'''
      \W\s[A-Z]$
     |(com.|d\.)
     |\(?adj.\)?
     |(all\.$)
     |^(Pays|région|lieu-dit
        |chef-lieu|canal|collégiale|ruisseau|bâtiment|hôpital
        |roi de|(bailliage|canton)(s?))
     |site|afflu(a|e)nt
     |forêt|village|église|état(s?)''', su, flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

The `re.VERBOSE` flag changes the parser to ignore *all* literal whitespace; the above expression is parsed as if all spaces, tabs and newlines are not present. Any `#` comments on a line are also stripped, from the `#` to the newline.